# I can't use django in coderunner 2

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, coderunner

I have been trying to import and use `django` in python, and it cant import any modules I installed via `pip`. 
When I downloaded `django` on the `command line` it said in anaconda which was outside my user. So I tried to put it in my user d=and see if that would help but it didn't.